# Observation about vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, raspberry-pi

I'm moving from C to C++ and was playing with vectors.

Here's some code I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std ;

#define VSIZE   10

class vClass ;
vector <vClass> myVect(VSIZE) ;

class vClass
{
    int pos1 ;

    public:
        void getInfo()
        {
            pos1 = this - myVect.data() ;

            cout << pos1 << endl ;
        }
};
//===============================

vClass vArray[VSIZE] ;

int main()
{

cout << endl << "Size of vClass: " << sizeof(vClass) << endl << endl ;

cout << "Size of myVect: " << sizeof(myVect) << endl << endl ;

cout << "Size of myVect[0]: " << sizeof myVect[0] << endl << endl ;

cout << endl  << "Locations:" << endl ;

for(int i= 0; i < VSIZE; i++) myVect[i].getInfo();

return 0 ;
}
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
Size of vClass: 8

Size of myVect: 12

Size of myVect[0]: 8

Locations:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I'm curious about the following:

1. Size of vClass is 8 bytes. But a 10 element vector of type vClass shows size of 12 bytes. Why is this ? I was expecting 8x10= 80 bytes.
2. The expression: `this - myVect.data()` results in outputting the index of the elements. 
   I expected I would need `(this - myVect,data())/sizeof(vClass)`.
   Is this always the case with vectors ?
   *I tried the same with an array : `vClass myArray[10]` and `(this - myArray)`
   but here i got a list of sequential hexadecimal numbers (addresses?)*. 
   So the 'this' pointer is somehow linked to the vector, but not the array ?

I'd appreciate if someone could explain or confirm this behaviour.

I am compiling this on a raspberry pi using g++ 4.9.2, using c++14 standard.

Thank you

Comment: You can't instantiate a vector of an incomplete type. You need the `vClass` definition *before* declaring `myVect`.

Comment: A vector is essentially a wrapped pointer to the heap with book keeping data. So it's constant size. Subtracting it from *this is not a good plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly this compiled in Visual Studio 2015.

> 1. Size of vClass is 8 bytes. But a 10 element vector of type vClass shows size of 12 bytes. Why is this ? I was expecting 8x10= 80 bytes.

Well, a `vector` is just a handle. Its elements are stored in the heap. All the `vector` needs is a pointer to these elements in the heap (`data`), the current number of elements (`size`) and the maximum number of elements (`capacity`).
So if you grow/shrink the vector, the handle's size always remains the same and only the array in the heap will change.

```
vector< vClass > myVect;

// Stack - vector
[ vector: data, size, capacity ]
            |
            |
            V
// Heap - array managed by vector
[ vClass0 ][ vClass1 ]...

// Each has completely unrelated addresses
```

> 2. The expression: this - myVect.data() results in outputting the index of the elements. I expected I would need (this -
>      myVect,data())/sizeof(vClass). Is this always the case with vectors ?
>      I tried the same with an array : vClass myArray[10] and (this -
>      myArray) but here i got a list of sequential hexadecimal numbers
>      (addresses?). So the 'this' pointer is somehow linked to the vector,
>      but not the array ?

This works because `this` and `myVect.data()` are both pointers to `vClass` in the managed array. You don't need to divide by `sizeof(vClass)` because pointer arithmetics take into account the size of the type they point to.

`sizeof(vClass) == sizeof(int)`, when you increment, decrement or subtract pointers they move in blocks the same size of the pointed type so you don't have to explicitly increment a pointer with the right size. You do get the indices 0,1,2,... but in other words that would also mean *2 vClass'es would fit between this address and this address*.

When you try this with an array of vectors, each vector is contiguous in memory (each handle). But also, each vector points to its own array in the heap so each array is completely unrelated. But I don't know exactly what code you tested with so I won't comment on that.

The `this` pointer, given that your `vClass` instances belong in the `vector`, is actually linked to the internal array of the `vector` and not to the `vector` handle itself.

---

This works because your class is a POD-class. If you were to make a vector of pointers (each instance would be in unrelated addresses), or use a pointer to a base class (each instance in an unrelated address AND derived types would have different sizes), then this wouldn't work.

Although this example works, I won't encourage you to do this (besides this only works because your vector is a global variable). You're moving from C to C++, and I understand old habits die hard, but avoid pointer arithmetics unless you really must use it.

You can get the `vector`'s size by (you got it right) calling the `size()` method, and if you need to know an element's index you will know when you iterate the vector. (There are other ways sure, but that's up to you)

**EDIT: About indices and iteration**

When you iterate arrays or vectors, you can iterate by index (among other forms of iteration). So obviously, each iteration you know one index,

```
for ( int i = 0; i < myVect.size(); ++i ) {
    myVector[ i ]; // <-- here's an object with index i, easy
}
```

Which is basically what you did when you printed your vector.

If you need to know a specific index without iterating (whether you need it to erase an element, or direct access, etc), you can, for example, have a separate container with relevant indices, or store it in the object as an ID, like,

```
class vClass {
    // ...
    int ID; // Or index, but I think ID sounds better
    // ...
};
```

Then when you push elements into the vector you can set their IDs and they will know their index. Of course, you have to update the indices yourself if you sort the vector. They won't "auto-update" like when you used the pointers, but your instances had to know exactly which container they were in and had to use implementation details to find their index (specifically for vectors), and contained objects shouldn't need to do that.

As I said there are many solutions to this. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your in depth response. Referring to your last paragraph, yes, the exercise was indeed to see how to extract the index of the element. Could you please elaborate on how to do this, as you did suggest this was possible 'when you iterate the vector' ?

Answer (score 2):

1. The vector object itself is always of a fixed size. It contains info like the number of elements and a pointer to some heap storage. The elements of the vector are stored on the heap, so that the number of elements can grow (or shrink).
2. Subtracting two pointers gives you the number of elements between the pointers. That is not specific for the vector. You seem to confuse this with a method to compute the size of an array (`sizeof(vArray)/sizeof(vClass)`). This is not needed with a vector, because it has a `size()` member.

The `this` pointer is only present inside member functions of classes. It tells you for which instance of the possibly many class objects the function has been called. When you do `myVect[i].getInfo()`, `this` will hold the address of `myVect[i]` while inside the `getInfo` function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I actually was looking for a way to fetch the index (position) of the class within the array. I outing that (this-myVect.getdata()) produced this result. I'm other words, if I call " myVect[i].getinfo()" I need to extract the value of i from within the class instance, for further use. Is there a proper way to achieve this? So far I have only discovered 'this - myVect.getdata ()' as the possible solution.

Comment: You generally don't know which container the class element is a part of, if any. Most often the member doesn't need to know that either. Your method works because all `vClass` objects happen to be stored in the same vector. Otherwise that wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(myVect)` tells you the size in bytes of the vector object itself (which is most likely 3 pointers internally). It says nothing about the number of elements stored in the vector; these are managed by the vector, but stored in dynamically allocated memory, so they don't imact `sizeof(myVect)`.

The information you were after is probably `myVect.size()`, which gives you the *number* of elements in the vector, or `myVect.size() * sizeof(vClass)`, which will give the number of bytes occupied by those vector elements. Note that the latter really says nothing about the memory used by the vector, which can over-allocate to keep space for adding elements, etc.

`this - myVect.data()` is most likely Undefined Behaviour, because you're not guaranteed to be working with pointers to the same array. But if it was well-defined, it would work like any other pointer arithmetic (same as in C): `a - b` where `a` and `b` are of type `T*` gives the number of `T` objects between `a` and `b`, not their distance in bytes.

---

As a side note: `std:vector` requires its template argument to be a complete type—it is an error to instantiate it with a class which is declared but not yet defined, as you're doing it. It may happen to (seem to) work, but that's pure chance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get this output, I get a compiler error as per juanchopanza's comment.

1. A `vector` object consists of (implementation-defined) metadata, including a *pointer* to the data it contains (the one you get from `data()`. You will find the size of the vector to be constant, not changing with its `size()`.
2. Your `this` pointer is of type `vClass *`. Pointer arithmetic on a pointer `p` always works with multiples of `sizeof( p )`.

That being said, you really shouldn't poke a class' internals like that. ;-)